# Sublayer is not showing up after add it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I'm trying to add the image `"resizeLayer"` over my UIView `selectedShape` by sublayering it over `selectedShape`

```
let sublayer = CALayer()
sublayer.bounds = selectedShape.bounds //even when inserted this line, sublayer still doesn't show up
sublayer.frame = selectedShape.frame
sublayer.contents = UIImage(named: "resizeLayer")
selectedShape?.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
```

But when I run my code I don't see the layer at all

I even tried subviewing the image `"resizeLayer"` over the UIView `"selectedShape"`

```
let resizeFrame = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "resizeLayer"))
resizeFrame.frame = selectedShape.frame
resizeFrame.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
selectedShape.addSubview(resizeFrame)
```

But still, the `"resizeLayer"` does not show up!

It only shows up if I add the `"resizeLayer"` to the overall view:

```
let resizeFrame = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "resizeLayer"))
resizeFrame.frame = selectedShape.frame
resizeFrame.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
selectedShape.addSubview(resizeFrame)     
self.view.insertSubview(resizeFrame, aboveSubview: selectedShape) //add this line
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated!

If it's relevant, this is how I made `selectedShape`

```
selectedShape = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
selectedShape.layer.cornerRadius = 10
selectedShape.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
canvas.addSubview(selectedShape) //canvas is the view I'm adding selectedShape to
```

[This is the image `"resizeLayer"` that I'm trying to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGyrZ.png)

The blue square is `selectedShape`. [As you can see the layer is not showing up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHFEa.png)

[What I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6ih1.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the entire frame for `selectedShape`. You should only use the `width` and the `height` because `x` and `y` should be **zero**. The image is added to `selectedShape` so the point `(0,0)` is the top left of the `selectedShape` view.

```
resizeFrame.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: selectedShape.frame.size)
```

I will admit that this stumped me for longer than it should have.

Answer (score 7):

Not really an answer to his problem, but related and would have saved me time if somone had written this here before. So in hope to help someone and compile a more complete list of problems and their solution:

The addSublayer call needs to be made from the main-thread...

The funny thing is if you do it from a worker-thread it still shows up in the view-hirarchy-debugging with the content you set, but it's not displayed...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should send selectedView to back:

```
canvas.sendSubviewToBack(selectedShape)
```

Comment: He does not want to add the `resizeImage` to the canvas.